# manually edit shortcuts on os x 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: keyboard, terminal, macos

I'm using TotalTerminal on 10.9 Mavericks and while it's not great, it's the best quake terminal I've found right now. I usually show/hide the visor using command-escape but unfortunately can't seem to pull this off as I'm being told there's an existing universal shortcut for this key combination.

I've gone through the keyboard preferences shortcuts and can't find anything that maps to command-escape. The only thing I can think of is that this used to be front-row (which is no longer installed by default on new macs).

Does anyone know how I can set command-escape manually in total terminal via config file? I'm happy doing that by modifying the apple keyboard shortcuts and erasing whatever is mapped their now or editing a totalterminal config.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`.
2. Quit Terminal.
3. Edit the plist in a text editor:

   ```
   <key>ToggleVisor</key>
   <dict>
     <key>KeyCode</key>
     <integer>53</integer> <!-- escape (see Events.h) -->
     <key>Modifiers</key>
     <integer>9437184</integer> <!-- command -->
   </dict>
   ```
4. Terminate the `cfprefsd` process from Activity Monitor.
5. Open Terminal.

Preference files are cached in 10.9, so if you edit a preference file directly, just quitting and reopening the application does not apply the changes. You can also run `defaults read com.apple.Terminal` instead of terminating `cfprefsd`.

Comment: This is not working for me.
something is changing it back whenever I restart total terminal.

Comment: @JohnHinnegan look at the other answer, you have to clear the cache for that file and it suggests that you have to restart your computer for that to happen.

Comment: @LauriRanta where did you got the keycodes from? I would need to do this for another key combination.

Comment: Found the keycodes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3202689/425741

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't leave a comment - not enough reputation...

The answer given by Lauri works, but you have to make sure that the cache of that `.plist` file is cleared. I achieved it by simply restarting the computer after editing the file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Feel free to edit such information into the answer directly.